# GPU parallelization of code that uses numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, gpu, numba

I'm trying to parallelize a Python function I wrote to run on multiple GPU cores simultaneously, but it seems like current methods for doing so, such as vectorize and guvectorize from numba, don't allow for anything more sophisticated than simple arithmetic operations in the function (https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2736).

My question is, is there a package or technique other than numba capable of handling functions that call numpy functions such as numpy.where or numpy.intersect1d?

Completely new to GPU programming here and not sure what the state-of-the-art capabilities are, so sorry if this question seems dumb.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If we're talking about a CUDA-capable GPU, you can try [CuPy](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/).